# Is there any better place to train for space travel than in a nuclear submarine?

Tags: space, training

As a nuclear submarine captain with 17 years at sea and also having written an advanced research project on adaptation of submarine technology to the space station, here are a few points to consider.

Atmosphere control: control of oxygen, CO<sub>2</sub> and other contaminants in a submarine is backed up by over 50 years of submarine operations. My ship could stay submerged indefinitely. I briefed the National Space Council and showed them that 50% of their O<sub>2</sub> band was above our fire prevention limit for submarine operations. I asked if they had a Freon 12 leak procedure. They use that in their food storage units on the space station. They did not. Their atmosphere analyzer heats the air to 600 degrees in the sampling procedure. At 600 degrees Freon 12 becomes hydrofluoric acid which will etch glass. The operating procedure said dicholoro difloura methane will drive the analyzer into saturation. The common name for that is Freon 12.

Casualty control in a closed space: Aircraft usually land when they have a fire. Subs can't. Their procedure isolated the space. Our procedure goes toward the fire to put it out. Their system automatically shot CO<sub>2</sub> at the flame, I asked where is the crew member going to go outside the electrical panel with the fire? He's going to die from CO<sub>2</sub>. They said he has a air pack. It lasted 10 minutes. So I said OK he's going to die in 10 minutes. Why don't you de-energize the panel?

Radiation control: they took care of this issue by raising the astronauts' limits to 10 times the level for nuclear workers. I designed them a portable shield for the habitation module as a storm shelter.

Comment: this doesn't really have a clear question and could be tagged better. i also don't see the worldbuilding aspect. maybe space se is a better fit?

Comment: what is the question you want us to answer? I won't downvote your question because you are new. Clarify it and people would answer it.

Comment: Do you mean a docked nuclear submarine, with engineers on standby, or submarine out in the sea?

Comment: It *is* a very good fit. The resource, space and equipment limitations match, or can be made to match for purpose. Communications lag can be simulated *very* easily. The isolation is spot-on. What is unavailable is Gravity, radiation and especially thermal aspects of the environment. Yes, while Earthbound, it is about as close as one can get in a preexisting facility or vehicle.

Answer (score 6):

Something like the Biosphere 2 project: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2, a simulated closed ecosystem, would be much less expensive to construct and operate as a training ground than a nuclear submarine, particularly if multiple teams are being trained in parallel.  Also, equipment in spacecraft and space stations have mass and design constraints (cooling, power, etc.) that submarine systems do not.  A Biosphere 2 like training environment could use more realistic equipment for space missions than a submarine could.